# Will the primary group of a user be deleted when you delete the user?

Tags: linux, users, group

I have created a user called `paul` using the following command:

```
sudo adduser paul
```

`adduser` also created a new group called `paul` and made it the primary group for the user `paul`.

I have created a file using the `paul` user, and displayed its information using `ls-l`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul paul 25 2017-05-14 15:30 1.txt
```

Then I have deleted the `paul` user using the following command:

```
sudo userdel paul
```

And then I have displayed the previously created file's information using `ls -l`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001 25 2017-05-14 15:30 1.txt
```

The `paul` user has been replaced by its ID (which is `1001`) since I have just deleted this user. But why the group ID is also displayed instead of the group name, was the group also deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Summary

Here is the short answer: When a user is deleted its primary group is also delete, unless that group also contains other users. In this latter case the user is deleted but the group is not.

We can easily verify this ourselves.

### Case 1: No other users in primary group of deleted user

First we consider the case where the primary group contains no other users.

Create the `paul` user:

```
root@host:~# useradd paul
```

Check for the `paul` group using `getent`:

```
root@host:~# getent group paul
paul:x:1001:
```

Delete the `paul` user:

```
root@host:~# userdel paul
```

Check for the `paul` group using `getent`:

```
root@host:~# getent group paul

root@host:~#
```

Notice that there is no output from this command. We can also try to delete the `paul` group ourselves:

```
root@host:~# groupdel paul
groupdel: group 'paul' does not exist
```

This confirms that the `paul` group no longer exists.

### Case 2: Additional users in primary group of deleted user

Now we will check to see what happens if we try to delete a user whose group contains other users:

```
root@host:~# useradd user1

root@host:~# useradd user2

root@host:~# usermod -a -G user1 user2

root@host:~# groups user2
user2 : user2 user1

root@host:~# userdel user1
userdel: group user1 not removed because it has other members.

root@host:~# groups user2
user2 : user2 user1

root@host:~# getent group user1
user1:x:1002:user2

root@host:~# getent passwd user1

root@host:~# deluser user1
/usr/sbin/deluser: The user `user1' does not exist.
```

In this case the `user1` *user* is deleted but the `user1` *group* remains.

Comment: But what if the primary group have multiple users, will deleting all of the users of this group cause the primary group to be deleted?

Comment: @user7681202 One sec - I'll update my solution.

Comment: Did the deletion of the user actually fail, or did it remove the user and keep the group?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I'm a jerk. You're absolutely right. I updated the solution. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @igal Also, based on my testing, the primary group will not be deleted if it has a different name than the user.